# How to properly save multi-line string into database

Tags: sql, database, string, text

I'm wondering how to properly save multi-line string into the database.

And the text saved should be OS independent.
For instance if I Java program that reads from database, it should get UNIX line endings on UNIX systems and WINDOWS line endings in windows.

Is such thing even possible?

Comment: Saving it is probably not the issue. The calling application must be able to replace the CRLF with the appropriate ones for that platform.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting. Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Thank you for you comments StingyJack and  Serge Belov.

And as for code. Files that I neede to save in the database were pgn files, which have such structure that I didn't need to save line endings. 
I was just wondering how to save line ending in case if ever work on something similar, so there basically is no code to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, but the database won't have a clue what format the line endings need to be in, nor should it care. It's up to the program retrieving the data to reformat line endings if/when needed.